# error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, compilation

When trying to "make" a file I keep getting the following error:

```
 error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
```

I can show the code to people who would like to see, but I would rather send it over a message.

I've searched some and some people suggest it's a compiling error that is common in "newer" compilers... and yes, I updated mine yesterday. Horrid idea.

Comment: You expect people to help you without you posting code?

Comment: I suggest that you return a value on the line that has a return statement with no value. I suspect this will fix the error.

Comment: Chances are the function expects you to return a king or a Jedi but you aren't returning either.

Comment: Judging by the error message, I'd say you've got `return;` somewhere - just a guess though.

Comment: This has nothing to do with updating compilers. Your code is broken. Did you even read the error message? You shouldn't strive to get rid of errors, you should strive to fix your code.

Comment: It isn't my code. So I'm respecting the person who wrote it by not posting it. I'm simply using and running it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error means that in your function:

```
void* foo(...);
```

You have a statement:

```
return;
```

But the compiler expects a value to be provided:

```
return myVoidPtr;
```